# Postgresql LEFT OUTER JOIN and performance

Tags: postgresql

I  have two tables: wells(id, name, extra_name) and geodesies(id, well_id, plot)

For this two tables query

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
wells.name, geodesies.plot
FROM "geodesies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "wells" ON "wells"."id" = "geodesies"."well_id"
ORDER BY LOWER("wells"."name_nso"), "wells"."extra_name"
LIMIT 10;
```

Output:

```
"Limit  (cost=1146.27..1146.29 rows=10 width=58) (actual time=64.482..64.488 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1146.27..1176.83 rows=12225 width=58) (actual time=64.480..64.484 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: (lower(wells.name_nso)), wells.extra_name"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 27kB"
"        ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=568.17..882.09 rows=12225 width=58) (actual time=11.214..56.280 rows=12225 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (geodesies.well_id = wells.id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on geodesies  (cost=0.00..251.25 rows=12225 width=23) (actual time=0.017..5.533 rows=12225 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=415.30..415.30 rows=12230 width=118) (actual time=11.126..11.127 rows=12230 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 16384  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1848kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on wells  (cost=0.00..415.30 rows=12230 width=118) (actual time=0.009..5.611 rows=12230 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.804 ms"
"Execution Time: 64.544 ms"
```

This query does not use any index.

If i remove order by from query:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
SELECT
wells.name, geodesies.plot
FROM "geodesies" LEFT OUTER JOIN "wells" ON "wells"."id" = "geodesies"."well_id"
LIMIT 10;
```

it uses index, and output looks like:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.57..2.86 rows=10 width=19) (actual time=0.042..0.146 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=0.57..2794.76 rows=12225 width=19) (actual time=0.040..0.142 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Merge Cond: (geodesies.well_id = wells.id)"
"        ->  Index Scan using index_geodesies_on_well_id on geodesies  (cost=0.29..979.64 rows=12225 width=23) (actual time=0.023..0.056 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using wells_pkey on wells  (cost=0.29..1631.73 rows=12230 width=28) (actual time=0.013..0.069 rows=10 loops=1)"
"Planning Time: 0.654 ms"
"Execution Time: 0.293 ms"
```

How to speed up query with order by clausle?

Regards

PostgresSQL 13

Comment: In order to find the first 10 rows based on a sort order, the database has to sort all rows from the table. And to sort all rows, it needs to retrieve all rows. And that is done most efficiently using a Seq Scan

Comment: `ORDER BY LOWER("wells"."name_nso"), ...` ORDER BY a function is always a showstopper.

Comment: @wildplasser: you can create an index with the expressions from the order by, but I doubt it would help here.

Comment: I know that, but I think it would be a bad idea, too. (ordering by a non-key of the left joined table is a kind of torture anyway ...)

Comment: [Disable sequential scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-query.html) to see how the query plan changes and if the execution time get's shorter.